# What is this icon?

Tags: notifications, lenovo

[image]

I have a Lenovo device, this icon  always appears and I am not sure which application is associated with this icon.

Comment: icon of Google assistant

Comment: @RahulGopi : if you are sure, why not make it an answer ? :)

Comment: This icon is similar to Google assistant, but, Google assistant don't show notification icon while its running in background. May be other person installed any app to activate assistant, and it is displayed there.